# Can this language be decided in polynomial time?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Let $L=${$0^{2^n}|n>=0$}
Can this be decided in polynomial time?
I can decide it in non polynomial time, by going over all '0's and delete 2 of them from the beginning and the end of the string, but can this be done in polynomial time as well?

Comment: Given $0^m$, how fast can a TM find out if $m$ is even or odd? In case $m$ is even, how fast can you compute $0^{m/2}$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Isn't it $O(logm)$, because I have to go over on $2^m$ digits?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in polynomial time. Because you should read all the $0$'s at least one time. In general if a string has length $m$ than time of decision process is $\Omega(m)$